# Workflow buttons Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm doing a workflow in a my module, I've declared the workflow xml in my `__openerp__` file, did all the button functions, added `state` selection field, and also have the `statusbar` in my view, this is one of the button functions:

```
def budget_validate(self,cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    if context is None:

        context = {}

    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'validate'}, context=context)

    return True
```

Just one, because no matter which I click, the error is the same, this is my field:

```
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('confirm', 'Confirm'),
        ('validate', 'Validate'),
        ('last', 'Last'),
        ('current1', 'Current1'),
        ('current2', 'Current2'),
        ('current', 'Current'),
        ('next', 'Next'),
        ('adjusted', 'Adjusted'),
        ('done', 'Done'),
    ], string="State", readonly=True, copy=False)
```

My view xml:

```
        <record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.budget.bsi.form</field>
        <field name="model">account.budget.bsi</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Sales Order">
                <header>
                    <button string="Confirm" name="confirm" states="draft" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Approve" name="validate" states="confirm" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Last" name="last" states="confirm" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Current 1" name="current1" states="last" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Current 2" name="current2" states="current1" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Current" name="current" states="current2" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Next" name="next" states="current" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Adjusted" name="adjusted" states="next" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Done" name="done" states="adjusted" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button name="draft" states="cancel" string="Reset to Draft" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Cancel Budget" name="cancel" states="confirm,validate" type="object" />
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,confirm,last,current1,current2,current,next,adjusted,done,cancel" clickable="True"/>
                </header> ...
```

Every time I click on any button it throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
AttributeError: 'account.budget.bsi' object has no attribute 'validate'
```

Originally, I've had those buttons as `type="workflow"` but in that case the buttons don't do anything. No error whatsoever, but states won't change.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart the server and update your module? If you did and it still does not work try `-u base`

Comment: Hi, I'm thinking this has something to do with old api, not sure, trying now

Comment: Yep, it was the old api, mixed up with new one, alhtough I think Odoov8 has a fallback, unlike v10, but anyways, gotta answer my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
@api.one
def budget_validate(self):
    self.write({'state': 'validate',})
```

Leave the `select` field as it is, and leave the buttons as objects on xml view.